# Why do sometimes white lines appear in my code like this?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

Anyone know why these lines sometimes appear and then stay all over my codebase? I can only remove them by restarting VScode.

OS: macos v12.1 but had it since v11
VScode: Always on the latest version

[image: vscode lines bug]

Comment: have you tries to disable graphics acceleration, see command line arguments of VSC

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, my first reaction is the role of a certain extension, and the possibility of its own setting is relatively small.
Since I don't know which extensions you have installed, can you check the installed extensions yourself and disable them to check it out? Focus on [these categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJeCG.png).

Comment: Did you find it's which extensions caused this? Are there any updates? I'm curious about this too.